# Rastrear Push abertos no parse

Tags: android, parse.com

Eu tenho uma aplicação no Parse.com que envia Pushs com mensagens de Api personalizadas para abrir uma Activity, o meu Custom Receiver é assim:

```
public class CustomReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "PUSH";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
    i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
    Log.d(TAG, intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}

@Override
protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG,"OPEN PUSH");
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);

}
```

No meu manifest está assim:

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.myapp.services.CustomReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        <action android:name="com.myapp.CustomAction" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Eu recebo os Pushs ok e até abre a Activity `MyClass.class`, mas no painel do Parse eu não consigo visualizar quantos usuários abriram o PUSH enviado. Visualizo apenas para quantos usuários foram enviados.

Comment: Mateus, poderia fazer um teste e usar o `trackAppOpened(intent)` ao invés do atual (Sei que não quer travar o `Receiver`, mas é só como teste.
Outra coisa, como está sua configuração do `ParseAnalytics`?

Comment: Testei continuou a mesma coisa. Agora não entendi sua pergunta quanto a configuração do Parseanalytcs @Wakim

Comment: É que pra usar o `ParseAnalytics` você precisa incluir o jar dele no projeto (já deve ter sido feito) e configurar ele no `onCreate` da sua `Application`. Consegue verificar esse segundo item?

Comment: O .jar do analytcs eu não adicionei não.. Adicionei apenas o 
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+' compile fileTree(include: 'Parse-*.jar', dir: 'libs') 
Como especificado aqui https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#analytics/events/mobile/android/native/existing

Comment: Mas dentro da pasta `libs` tem o `jar`? Minha sugestão é você adicionar o `jar` caso não tenha e inicializar o `ParseAnalytics` no `onCreate`.

Comment: No SDK do parse não tem nenhum ParseAnalytcs.jar.. @Wakim

Comment: Hmm, confundi com o `ParseCrashReporting`. Olhando a doc. está certo o modo como está usando e nem é preciso configurar no `Application`. Erro meu. No caso, está salvando a `ParseInstallation` né?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30315/discussion-between-mateus-carvalho-and-wakim).

Comment: @Wakim sim estou...

Comment: Parece que o push open está com bug.. Vi várias pessoas postando isso no fórum do facebook de developers..